# Multiple clipboards software for Windows

Tags: windows

### I am looking for a program that lets me use many clipboards at the same time (around 100)

#### The software needs to remember each clipboard when I restart the computer

For example:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>     - Save to first clipboard
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>     - Save to second clipboard
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>     - Save to third clipboard
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> - Save to [4-9]th clipboard
>
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - Paste from first clipboard
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - Paste from second clipboard
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> - Paste from [3-9]th clipboard

This is only 10 clipboards.
When I press, for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, it would change the clipboard set (1-10, 11-20, etc...).
I want to have 10 clipboard sets.
Each set would be for an other project (or other user)

Answer (score 2):

I found the software:
http://clipjump.sourceforge.net/ (open source)

It's  very customiazable, so I can do with it everything I want.

```
The program was created to overcome some of the limits other clipboard managers had.
Use of Shortcuts other than Ctrl+X,C,V
No preview of Printscreen captures stored on Clipboard.
Limited number of Clipboards.
Take long to switch between multiple - clipboards.
Shareware

Here are few reasons to like Clipjump.
It Captures every change on Clipboard regardless of data-types.
Supports preview of Clipboard stored images such as Printscreen captures.
Control Multiple-Clipboards only by using the single shortcut Ctrl+V (which is also configurable)
Can have as much as simultaneous clipboards as possible, no LIMIT.
Very (very) fast Clipboard switching.
Fast and powerful searching to help find needed content while pasting.
Batch/Multiple Pasting
Highly Configurable, thanks to ClipjumpCustom
Not touches the registry and System drive.
Multilingual, free, portable, Unicode, open source
```

[image]

Comment: I have asked the developers (Avi), and he told me that he will implement shortcut for each clip and even maybe to buffers/set. I will update you when it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

[ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) can remember up to 1024 clipboards and saves history across sessions, works on Windows XP through to 8. Whilst it doesn't support any idea of sets of clipboards, it does have many of the features you are asking for and is a fast, lightweight program that has been reliable in my experience. The only conflict I have found is with Excel, which sometimes says it can't clear the clipboard, so you right click on the tray icon and disable ClipX if this is a problem while using Excel, which has it's own clipboard quirks.

Comment: The answer would have been better if you had provided some key features, a screenshot demonstrating how you use it, what are its weak points etc.

Comment: How many distinct clipboard buffers does it handle?

Comment: Also FYI ClipX is no longer supported.

Comment: Indeed, latest stable version is from 30 November 2005 and latest beta is from 6 July 2008

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - ClipX may not be supported, but it works great (I use it on a Win 7 x64 system). It's lightweight and fast.

Answer (score 0):

There is many around, but not many are free. Preferring free ones I'm using

#### [3D Clipboard](http://3dclipboard.com/)

[image]

It has the following options:

[image]

It features:

- Sticky items that will remain on the menu until deleted.
- Items can contain placeholders allowing you to create reusable templates.
- Items can be rearranged by dragging them on the menu.
- Item size (in characters and/or lines) can now be included in the clip menu.
- *Actions* provides support for various extended macro operations, for example you can run `UrlEncode()` and `UrlDecode()` in actions.
- Tab, CR, and LF characters are shown as arrows.
- Unicode support.
- Notification icon now reappears after explorer.exe crash.
- Clipboards are pesisted across Sessions.
- Items can be editec.
- Handles up to 99 clipboard entries, only one is available at given time – it is actually current clipboard.

**Note:** Hotkeys work differently from what you expect. Added items queue up (see first screenshot). Keyboard acceleators are assigned to recent 36 items (1..9, 0, A..Z) so if you press a hotkey (*Normal* or *AutoPaste*, see second screenshot) then you can select one of 36 items by pressing its accelerator.

[More screenshots >>](http://3dclipboard.com/screenshots)

**Regarding 10 sets of 10 items:** I haven't seen single clipboard manager with this feature so far. If no one gives you satisfactory answer, maybe you could consider writing one once more...

Comment: How many distinct clipboard buffers does it handle?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt – no application can actually offer more than one buffer because Windows provides only one :). They can *pretend* more by putting selected one into clipboard or by similar technique.

Comment: Yes I think the OP's idea is to have an application supporting several clipboard buffers (which can be done using one specific shortcut for each buffer). E.g. Ditto can be set to have 3 different buffers.